# TypeScript two digits addition returns a string concatenation

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
const x = 1;
const y = ('3' as unknown) as number;

let add = (num1: number, num2: number)=> {
    return num1 + num2;
}

console.log(add(x, y));
```

// prints 13

Where it is supposed to print 4
as "const y" is converted to "number" type

Comment: `const y` is **not** converted to a number. You've just tricked the compiler into thinking it's a number. And now you're paying the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const y = ('3' as unknown) as number;` is not converting the string to a number. You are only doing a type assertion here.

So, what JS is doing : `1 + '3' = 13`.

You would need to do something like `Number('3')` to fix that issue. But be wary, `Number()` can return `NaN`.

Comment: but isn't it supposed that add(x: number, y: number) to return an error that y is not a number?

Comment: Yes it would if you didn't explicitly change the type with your assertion `as unknown as number`